# request in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, mysqldatareader

I work with this code:

```
   <form  method="get" name="MobileDetails">
 <input name="brand" id="brand" value="<?php echo $brand;?>" type="hidden">
<input name="brid" id="brid" value="<?php echo $brandid;?>" type="hidden">
 <button type="button" name="submitButton" value="get Details"    onclick="getDetails()">    
</form>
```

java script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getDetails(){
var brand = document.getElementById('brand').value;
var brandid = document.getElementById('brid').value;
document.MobileDetails.action = 'details.php?brand='+brand+'&id='+brandid;
document.MobileDetails.submit();
}
</script>
```

But it does not work in while loop. Whats the problem? My code is given below.
When i click on the button it do not do anything. But the code work great with out while loop given on the top.

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php'); 
$SQL= "SELECT*FROM mobile ORDER BY price ASC  LIMIT 10";
$result= mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $brand=$db_field['brand'];
 $id=$db_field['id'];
 $model=$db_field['model'];
 echo "<form  method='get' name='MobileDetails'>";
 echo " <input name='brand' id='brand' value='". $brand ."' type='hidden'>";
 echo" <input name='brid' id='brid' value='". $id ."' type='hidden'>";
 echo" <input name='mod' id='mod' value='". $model ."' type='hidden'>";
 echo" <button type='button' name='submitButton' value='get Details'   onclick='getDetails()'/>    
  </form>   ";
  echo "CLICK HERE";
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using several times the same id. Ids have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Uou are dealing with multiple id's. The job of an ID is to be unique identifier for the element. I suggest just using

```
 <form action="details.php" type="get">
```

this will do exactly what you are trying to achieve without using the function.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with element ID's is that they need to be unique for the page; however, as you may see, not required for HTML to be displayed. When calling your JS function `getDetails()`, it grabs the element by ID but when you have multiple ID's in the page, this will fail.

So what can you do? Well, in your loop, you create a new form for each 'brand'. You can pass a reference of the form to the `grabdetails` and then, by **NAME**, grab the values from that form.

---

Rather than using Javascript to generate a link based on given details put in a hidden field, you should just generate the action at the PHP level.

```
echo "<form  method='get' name='MobileDetails' action='details.php?brand=$brand&id=$brandid'>";
```

But since you do have hidden fields, using just `action='details.php'` the form will take the user to

```
details.php?brand={brand}&brid={id}&mod={model}
```

You should look into `POST` or making your button into a plain link rather than having a form.

Comment: @RahulMitra did you change your code to work with my suggestion or just change the two spots? The JS function you need to remove your two `var` lines

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function getDetails(brand, branid){
document.MobileDetails.action = 'try.php?brand='+brand+'&id='+brandid;
document.MobileDetails.submit();
}
</script>

Comment: echo" <button type='button' name='submitButton' value='get Details' onclick='getDetails($brand, $id)'/>

Comment: @RahulMitra see my new bottom answer